# Vba Goto won't work properly

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, goto

Hi all I've been playing around with "If" "Then" "And" and "Goto"

I think I got the hang of all except the "Goto" many times I can't get it to work 
I'm not sure if it's because I'm using the "If" wrong or it's because I use the "Goto" wrong. Can someone please take a look  at this code to tell me what I am doing wrong with it. Because I use "If" statements a lot so it would be nice if I'm using it the best and right way. And yes I know in the following code that I use the activesheet and I should do the code without working with a activesheet as many people in here stats but I'm not sure yet how to use the

```
Columns(1).Insert Shift:=xlRight
```

yet without activation the sheet

So here is the code I do have cell A1 with the Value "new" so the Goto should be activated but its not.

```
Sub con()
Set tsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Players")
Sheets("Players").Activate
ActiveSheet.Columns(1).Insert Shift:=xlRight
Dim lngLastRow As Long
If tsheet.Range("A1") = "new" Then
GoTo AlR
Else
    lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A2").Formula = "=B2 & "" "" & C2 & "" "" & G2 & "" "" & D2"
    Range("A2").Copy Range("A2:A" & lngLastRow)
    tsheet.Range("A1").Value = "new"
End If
AlR:
MsgBox "Column is already present"
End Sub
```

Comment: Its because you are using `GoTo` in the same line. Put GoTo in next line and the code block in `If` in `Else` part.

Comment: Just remove the End If

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make yourself and the future a favor: don't use GOTOs for anything else than error handling.

What you are doing now is called [Spaghetti code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code).

Your code should be :

```
Sub con()
Set tsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Players")
Sheets("Players").Activate
ActiveSheet.Columns(1).Insert Shift:=xlRight
Dim lngLastRow As Long
If tsheet.Range("A1") = "new" Then 
    MsgBox "Column is already present"
else
    lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A2").Formula = "=B2 & "" "" & C2 & "" "" & G2 & "" "" & D2"
    Range("A2").Copy Range("A2:A" & lngLastRow)
    tsheet.Range("A1").Value = "new"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I agree that `GoTo` should be considered harmful (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Considered_harmful), but you could mention that it is required for error handling in VBA.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it is much appreciated !

Comment: Thanks for the link Noceo

Comment: @noceo I havent edited my answer at all since you posted this comment. COuld you read it again correctly please? Because "error handling" exception is already there.

Comment: Funny thing is it is still not reading the new in cell A1 (I just wrote new in the cell so it should work right?

Comment: and just to check I used this and it gives back a True

    `=IF(A1="new",TRUE,FALSE)`

Comment: This is a logic issue, we can't answer without seeing data. Maybe just replace the `=` with  `<>` in `If tsheet.Range("A1") = "new" Then`

Comment: That worked ? is = not used the same way as in formula hmm I have to look this up now

Comment: @ThomasG my apologies, i missed the error handling part. Maybe if you make it bold, people (like myself) who havent had enough coffee, will also notice it :-).